# shell_exec() doesn't run Azure xplat-cli commands

Tags: php, azure

I'm trying to use Azure's `xplat-cli` to run the following two commands from a PHP script:

`azure account import azure.publishsettings`

`azure site create newsite --location='West US'`

The above two commands execute perfectly from the same /var/www folder within Terminal, but don't run when called from PHP. I'm using the following PHP code to run the commands and debug the output:

```
$command = "azure account import azure.publishsettings";            
$out = shell_exec($command); 
echo $out;
```

I've set PHP to report all errors, but I do not receive any errors (I was thinking it would throw an error if the operation timed out). `echo $out` does not display any output, although it works perfectly with other command line commands.

I tried using different azure commands, but even `azure` and `azure -v` return no output. I've tried using `chmod` to change permissions for the `bin` directory and the `azure` executable so that PHP's `www-data` user can execute it. However, it still doesn't work.

What could be the possible problem(s)?